# Menu com bolinhas vertical e horizontal

Tags: html, css

Como eu posso fazer esses dois menus?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu peguei do site do Twitter, mas não queria pegar os códigos deles, como eu posso fazer isso? de forma que eu possa adicionar infinitos numeros com suas respectivas descrições..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para fazer isso é necessário utilizar a função `counter()` da propriedade `content` dentro de pseudo-elemento CSS `::before` de cada item da lista. ([Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters)).

Para o posicionamento utilize margens, *padding* e posicionamento absoluto. Para o circulo, utilize a propriedade `border-radius`. Na opção horizontal é só reposicionar os `<li>` com `display: inline-block;` e alterar os valores de posição e espaço. Para ficar igual só faltou remover os "excessos" dos lados.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
li::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item);
  position: absolute;
  left: -37px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px blue solid;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
ol.hori {
  display: inline-block;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 0;
}
ol.hori li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
ol.hori li::before {
  top: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item a</li>
  <li>item b</li>
  <li>item c</li>
</ol>
<ol class="hori">
  <li>item a</li>
  <li>item b</li>
  <li>item c</li>
</ol>
```